# How to build a project in eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm developing a plugin in eclipse which should build the project (and do other stuff) on click of a button. I'm just searching for the line to build the selected project.

Answer (score 0):

The `IProject` for the project has several build methods depending on exactly what you want to do. The simplest is:

```java
IProject project = ....

IProgressMonitor monitor = ... a progress monitor ...

project.build(IncrementalProjectBuilder.FULL_BUILD, monitor);
```

Comment: How do i get the active project and how to implement the monitor?

Comment: What do you mean by 'active project', Eclipse has no such concept? You can use `NullProgressMonitor` or a monitor given to you by a `Job`  or `IRunnableWithProgress` it all depends on how you are running this.

Comment: by 'active project' i mean the one I have selected in the workspace. for example if I press build in eclipse the project i have selected will be build, if it's possible (c/c++).

Comment: How you do that depends on where you are running the code. In a command handler you might use `HanderUtil.getActiveSelection`.